# VerticalなStackViewの中に置いたViewの左右に10ポイントの空白を設けたいが、Conflicting Constraintsする

Tags: swift, ios, autolayout

添付画像のように`VerticalなStackView`の中に置いた`View`の左右に`10ポイント`の空白を設けたいが、`Conflicting Constraints`してしまいます。

- そもそも何故コンフリクトしているのかわかっていない

  - 自分が付けたのは`View.leading = leading + 10` なので、何故 `leading = View.leading`がいるのか理解できてない（おそらくStackViewのせいだと思いますが...）
- 吹き出しに`Select or more constraints to delete:` とあるので自分が付けた記憶のない `leading = View.leading` を選択して `Delete Constraints`ボタンを押そうとしたが、そもそも`leading = View.leading`を何故かUI的に選択できない（チェックボックスが反応しない）

という状況です。

どうすれば左右に空白を設けることができるのでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIStackViewに追加したビューの位置はすべてUIStackViewによって管理されます。ビューとUIStackViewに直接の制約を設定することはできません。

縦方向のUIStackViewなら横方向の位置は右/左/中央寄せ、幅いっぱいに広げる、の中から選ぶことになります。その設定と内部のビューのIntrinsicContentSizeによって位置が決定します。

これを踏まえて期待通りの結果を得るには大きく２つの方法があります。

まずUIStackViewとスーパービューの関係としてLeading/Trailingに10ptの制約をつけることです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

もう一つの方法として、UIStackViewの内部のビューを入れ子にしてUIStackViewに直接追加されたビューに対して制約をつけることです。

UIStackViewとビューに制約をつけることはできませんが、入れ子のビューとビューにはいくらでも制約をつけることができます。

どちらを使用するかはケースバイケースですが、後者の方法をマスターしておくと、UIStackViewとの組み合わせて表現できるレイアウトの幅がかなり広がり、応用力が身につきます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

stackviewのalignmentをcenterにすれば解決します